# Angular 2 @Input() decorator for object with Date type property

Tags: javascript, angular, asp.net-web-api2

I have a component which acts as a dumb child and takes an object via an @Input() type from it's parent.

This object (a person) has a property/field 'dob' which is of type Date.

Here is parent component constructor fetching the person from a route resolve which it will then pass to the child components @Input().

```
 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
          private authService: AuthenticationService,
          private personService: PersonService) {

    this.route.data.subscribe(result => {
    this.person = Object.assign({}, result['data'].person);
    console.log('PERSON PARENT DATE: ' + this.person.dob);

  },
  error => {
    console.log('PersonOverviewComponent - Error getting resolve data: ' + error);
  });
}
```

Here is the child component:

```
export class MyDetailsOverviewComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() person: Person;
  @Input() member: Member;
  @Input() personIsMember: boolean;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private authService: AuthenticationService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('PERSON CHILD DATE: ' + this.person.dob);
  }

}
```

And the parent template binding to the @Input()

```
  <div class="row">
       <div class="offset-sm-1 col-sm-5">
          <my-details-overview
              [person]="person"
              [member]="member"
              [personIsMember]="personIsMember">
          </my-details-overview>
        </div>
  <div *ngIf="personIsOfficial" class="offset-sm-1 col-sm-4">
      <emergency-info-overview
          [info]="emergencyInfo"
          [person]="person"
          [personOfAge]="personOfAge">
        </emergency-info-overview>
  </div>
```

Here is the service which gets the person object and assigns the date returned from the .Net web api.

```
getPerson(id: string): Observable<Person> {
    let params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('id', id);
    return this.http.get(this.config.apiEndpoint + '/People/', {search: params})
      .map((r: Response) => {
        let person = r.json() as Person;
        person.dob = new Date(r.json().dob);
        this.utilities.cleanApiResponseData(person);
        return person;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('PersonService Error: ' + error);
        return Observable.throw(error);
      });
}
```

The output to the console for person.dob from the parent component shows:

**PERSON PARENT DATE: Thu Dec 15 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)**

However, output to the console for person.dob from the child component shows:

**PERSON CHILD DATE: null**

The person object itself in the child is valid with the exception of the dob property. Here is the person @Input() member printed to console from child.

```
PERSON CHILD DATE: {
   "rowId":6,
   "aspNetUserId":"#########",
   "email":"#####",
   "title":"Mr",
   "forename":"James",
   "surname":"Brown",
   "address1":"#####",
   "address2":"",
   "address3":"",
   "address4":"",
   "town":"BIGGLESWADE",
   "county":"Bedfordshire",
   "country":"USA",
   "postCode":"#####",
   "daytimePhone":"",
   "eveningPhone":"",
   "mobile":null,
   "dob":null
}
```

My question is how do I take a copy of the Date type property on the person object when passing it to the childs @Input() person member ?

I'm assuming I'm missing something here due to the Date property being a reference type but can't workout how to get this working.

Thanks in advance.

Person object model is below for reference:

```
export class Person {
  aspNetUserId: string;
  email: string;
  title: string;
  forename: string;
  surname: string;
  address1: string;
  address2: string;
  address3: string;
  address4: string;
  town: string;
  county: string;
  country: string;
  postCode: string;
  daytimePhone: string;
  eveningPhone: string;
  mobile: string;
  dob: Date;
  updatedBy: string;
  updatedOn: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to resolve this by doing the following in the child component:

```
export class MyDetailsOverviewComponent implements OnInit {

    private person: Person;
    @Input() set personInput (person: Person) {
    this.person = Object.assign({}, person);
    this.person.dob = new Date(person.dob);
  }

  @Input() member: Member;

  @Input() personIsMember: boolean;


  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private authService: AuthenticationService) {

  }


  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('PERSON CHILD DATE: ' + this.person.dob);
  }

}
```

Would this be the correct approach ?

Comment: The person passed into the set still has a null value for dob property